# C# .NET / FireWire IEEE 1394

Tags: c#, .net, video, stream, firewire

I'm currently working on a project where it is needed to interact with a standart USB Camera (get video stream).
I'm actualy using the **AForge.Video.DirectShow** library under .NET to accomplish this task.
Now, the usb camera will be changed for a FireWire **IEEE1394** camera, unfortunatly, it seems that DirectShow does not support (yet) this type of device.

Does someone know any library implemented on .NET suporting the IEEE1394 standart ?

Comment: You should be able to use [WIA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368(VS.85).aspx) to capture images or videos from any device whether its USB, Firewire, etc... Look for a tutorial [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Webcam-Capture-50295c7f)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! FYI, questions asking for libraries are [off topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289843/can-i-ask-for-code-libraries-and-plugins-on-stack-overflow-or-is-that-better-su) here. If you already have code written but it's not working, we'd be happy to help with that.

Comment: Thancks for your reply @Icemanind , I'll figure it out...